# Offset subquery in lead/lag

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I've got tracking data that I modify the start and end dates using LEAD and LAG to make sure the previous End time equals the next Start time. These queries are partitioned over a groupId, ordered by the start time.

My issue is when one of the records has a start and end time that encompasses the following two or more records.  I need to flag these encompassed records for review.

I have no issue with this if it's just one record, since I can use the LAG query to look at the previous end time and then flag it.  However if it's two or more records later, I can't do this without the offset parameter.

I'm having issues writing the offset subquery so that it correctly checks for a record that has an encompassing range.

```
GroupId  Id          Start                 End
1613833 81477   19/04/2014 10:47    19/04/2014 14:38
1613833 38813   19/04/2014 14:38    19/04/2014 17:45
1613833 15874   19/04/2014 14:46    19/04/2014 15:00
1613833 89773   19/04/2014 15:00    19/04/2014 16:30
```

In this case, record 15874 would be flagged using

```
LAG(END) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY Start) > END
```

, but 89773 wouldn't.

I have no idea how to write an offset subquery that handles a situation like this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `lag()`/`lead()`.  Just use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.groupid = t.groupid and
                    t2.start < t.start and
                    t2.end > t.end
             );
```

Comment: this works over a small subset, but is too slow with my full dataset

Comment: Try adding an index on `table(groupid, start, end)`.